# Set Snow Leopard to use python 2.5 rather than 2.6

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I just upgraded to Snow Leopard and I'm trying to get it to use the old python 2.5 install.  I had with all my modules in it.  Does anyone know how to set the default python install to 2.5?

Comment: This sounds like it might be more of a superuser question, but it could go either way.

Comment: Your right - but I found the answer - defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.

Comment: +1 for writing a title that makes it easy to find. I had the same question just today and I found the answer in less than a minute :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I worked this out - if you have this problem open a terminal and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.5
```

Comment: This is documented in the python man page that came with Snow Leopard

Comment: You can find the man page that describes it here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/python.1.html

Answer (score 0):

You want [`python_select`](http://python_select.darwinports.com/).

> Description: Switch the default python interpreter

Comment: That only works for MacPorts-installed versions of Python, not the Apple-supplied ones.